# What does the module keyword mean in C# and why it is not in keyword list?

Tags: c#, keyword, language-specifications

I found strange `System.AttributeTargets` value - `AttributeTargets.Module`. I searched it's usages and found this C# code:

```
[module: ContractNamespace("http://tempuri.org")]
```

It is an attribute on a something called "module".

What does this `module` mean in C#? Why can't I find it in the [keyword list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb(v=vs.120).aspx)? Isn't it a keyword? When is it used?

Comment: See Attribute Targets in [Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I think my question is more about C# language, and proposed duplicate is about .net-wide concept

Comment: That's because it's a .NET concept. C# doesn't really have much to "add" on top of it.